# ¿Como determinar que un ISBN es válido?

Tags: c#, isbn, validacion-isbn

**Esta pregunta es autorespondida.**

A continuación se muestra un algoritmo para determinar si un **ISBN** de 10 dígitos o 13 dígitos es válido.

Para determinar si un **ISSN** es válido entre aquí: [¿Cómo determinar que un ISSN es válido?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/494292/como-determinar-que-un-issn-es-valido/494293#494293)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El **ISBN** (International Standard Book Number / Número Estándar Internacional  de Libros) es un identificador único para libros (exactamente igual a como ocurre con un DNI o carnet de identidad para personas). Existen **ISBN de 10 dígitos** (en extinción), el cual se estructura en cuatro partes:

**1)** Código del país o lengua de origen

**2)** El editor

**3)** El número del artículo

**4)** Dígito de control

Estas partes varían en longitud y para facilitar la lectura se suelen separar de manera opcional por espacios o guiones.

A medida que se fueron agotando los **ISBN de 10 dígitos** se empieza a adoptar un nuevo estándar de 13 dígitos. Cada uno tiene diferentes formas de validarse, a continuación propongo el siguiente algoritmo para validar **ISBN de 10 y 13 dígitos**:

```
static class Validaciones
{
    public static bool ValidarISBN(string isbn)
    {
        bool validado = false;
        var listaNumeros = new List<int>();
        var indiceX = isbn.IndexOf('X');

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(isbn))
        {
            if (isbn.Length == 10)
            {
                if (indiceX == 9 || indiceX == -1)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
                    {
                        listaNumeros.Add(Convert.ToInt32(isbn[i].ToString()) * (i + 1));
                    }

                    var modulo = listaNumeros.Sum() % 11;
                    var digitoControl = (isbn[9] == 'X') ?
                                         10 : Convert.ToInt32(isbn[9].ToString());

                    validado = (digitoControl == modulo);                                    
                }
            }
            else if (isbn.Length == 13)
            {
                if (indiceX == -1)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++)
                    {
                        listaNumeros.Add((i % 2 == 0) ?
                                          Convert.ToInt32(isbn[i].ToString()) :
                                          Convert.ToInt32(isbn[i].ToString()) * 3);
                    }
        
        var modulo = listaNumeros.Sum() % 10;

                    modulo = (modulo == 10) ? 0 : 10 - modulo;  

                    var digitoControl = Convert.ToInt32(isbn[12].ToString());

                    validado = (digitoControl == modulo);
                }
            }
        }

        return validado;
    }
}
```

Este método recibe como parámetro un **string**, el cual será el **ISBN** a validar y devuelve un **booleano**, devolviendo **true**, si el **ISBN** es válido y **false** en caso contrario.

Declaramos tres variables:

**validado:** Variable de tipo **bool**, que nos servirá para saber si el **ISBN** es o no válido y devolver dicho valor, se inicializa en **false**.

**listaNumeros:** Variable de tipo **lista de enteros**, la cual nos permitirá almacenar individualmente cada número del **ISBN** para realizar determinadas operaciones.

**indiceX:** Variable de **tipo entero** que nos servirá para saber si existe una **'X'** en el **ISBN de 10 dígitos**, ya que el **ISBN de 10 dígitos** solamente admite números del **0-9** para cualquiera de las **10** posiciones y el caracter **'X'** solamente en la última posición, la **'X'** representa el número **10**, es decir en la última posición del código **ISBN** pudiera haber o bien un dígito del **0-9** o bien un caracter **'X'**, sin embargo el caracter **'X'**, de existir solamente aparecerá en la última posición.

Posterior a la declaración de variables preguntamos si el **ISBN** está vacío, de estarlo, evidentemente devolvemos **false**, ya que no se cumplen las reglas de validación, de no estarlo entonces preguntamos si tiene **10** dígitos. En caso de tener **10** dígitos nos aseguramos de que si existe el caracter **'X'**, este solamente se encuentre en la última posición. Verificado todo lo anterior procedemos entonces a comprobar que el dígito de control es válido (Recuerda que es el último caracter del **ISBN**).

El dígito de control de un **ISBN de 10 dígitos** se halla mediante el cálculo basado en el **módulo 11**, este algoritmo consiste en multiplicar cada uno de los nueve primeros dígitos por la posición que ocupan en la secuencia numérica, es decir el primer dígito se multiplica por **1**, el segundo por **2** y así sucesivamente hasta el noveno dígito que se multiplica por **9**. Luego se suman todas estas multiplicaciones y el resultado se divide entre **11**. Esta división dejará un resto entre **0** y **9**. Si el resto está entre **0** y **9** este mismo valor será el dígito de control, pero si el resto es **10** entonces el dígito de control será el caracter **'X'**.

Lo descrito anteriormente es lo que hace el **ciclo for**, es decir se va recorriendo cada número de la secuencia y multiplicándolo por la posición que ocupa en dicha secuencia, guardándose estas multiplicaciones en la **lista de enteros listaNumeros**. Después de salir del **ciclo for** se llama al **método Sum**, para que se sumen todos los valores guardados en la lista y a esta suma se le halla el **módulo 11**. Si este cálculo es igual al último caracter del **ISBN** entrado como parámetro entonces
tendremos un **ISBN de 10 dígitos** correctamente validado.

En caso de que el **ISBN tuviera una longitud de 13 dígitos**, verificamos que el caracter **'X'** no ocupa ninguna posición ya que en el **ISBN de 13 dígitos** solamente se admiten dígitos del **0** al **9**. Posteriormente procedemos a validar el dígito de control.

El dígito de control de un **ISBN de 13 dígitos** se halla con un cálculo basado en el **módulo 10**, multiplicando el primero de los números por **1**, el segundo por **3**, el tercero por **1**, el cuarto por **3**, y así sucesivamente hasta llegar al dígito que ocupa la posición **12**, el dígito de control es el valor que se debe añadir a la suma de todas estas multiplicaciones para que sea divisible por **10**. Por ejemplo si la suma es **97**, el dígito de control sería **3**, ya que **97 + 3 = 100**, y **100** es divisible por **10**.

Lo descrito anteriormente es lo que se hace dentro del **ciclo for**, es decir se va recorriendo cada número de la secuencia y si es una posición par, se multiplica por **1**, si es una posición impar se multiplica por **3**, guardándose estas multiplicaciones en la **lista de enteros listaNumeros**. Después de salir del **ciclo for** se llama al **método Sum** para que se sumen todos los valores guardados en la lista y a esta suma se le halla el **módulo 10**, y dicho módulo se le resta al número **10**, obteniendo de esta forma el dígito de control. Si este número obtenido es igual al último caracter del **ISBN** entrado como parámetro entonces tendremos un **ISBN de 13 dígitos** correctamente validado.

Como se usa **Linq** debemos poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar regex tambien, revisa esta  [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271613/use-regex-to-verify-an-isbn-number)

`(\d{10,13}).*?_(\d{3})|(\d{3}).*?_(\d{10,13})|(\d{10,13})(?=[^\d])` o
`^(?=(?:\D*\d){10}(?:(?:\D*\d){3})?$)[\d-]+$`

```
var isbn = "978-1-56619-909-4";
//true or false

var validationISBN= Regex.Match(isbn , @"(\d{10,13}).*?_(\d{3})|(\d{3}).*?_(\d{10,13})|(\d{10,13})(?=[^\d])").Success;
```

si quieres usar ambos regex en la misma linea, usa el `|` quedando de esta manera

```
var validationISBN= Regex.Match(isbn , @"(^(?=(?:\D*\d){10}(?:(?:\D*\d){3})?$)[\d-]+$)|(^(?=(?:\D*\d){10}(?:(?:\D*\d){3})?$)[\d-]+$)").Success;
```

Comment: No es completamente cierto que puedas utilizar regex para validar un ISBN. Sí puedes validar con regex si **es un formato ISBN válido**, es decir, si consta de 10 o 13 dígitos, y están ordenados de cierta manera, pero no para validar su autenticidad. Un comentario en la respuesta que enlazas dice: *You can't validate an ISBN with regex. The final digit is a checksum and needs to be computed.*. Si aclaras este punto en tu respuesta, es un complemento ideal para la respuesta de Javp

Comment: @Arriel Es cierto lo.que dices, si lees la segunda respuesta, ahi habla  de la solución que mencionas