# Como encontrar un objeto en un ArrayList

Tags: java

Necesito encontrar en un `ArrayList<Libro>` un `Libro` a través de un parámetro pasado(isbnrecibido). el parámetro que recibe(isbn) es un atributo de tipo `int` del objeto Libro, pero no consigo dar con la fórmula dentro del `for` para dar con el libro. La funcionalidad también pide que si encuentra el libro lo guarda en:
**librorespuesta**

Este es mi còdigo:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < coleccion1.size(); i++) {
         if(isbnrecibido == coleccion1(i).getisbn()) {
            librorespuesta = coleccion1.get(i);
            System.out.println(coleccion1.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Amigo ten cuidado con "==" ya que normalmente sirve para comparar direcciones de memoria de un objeto, a no ser que compares tipos primitivos (int, short, char...) pero si quieres comparar que 2 objetos son iguales utiliza el método equals()

Comment: Es casì correcto lo que realizas,  para comparar usa la funciòn `.equals(..)` o `.equalsIgnoreCase(..)` ,agreguè respuesta, saludos.

Comment: Una cosa muy importante, el isbn aunque este compuesto por numeros, no debe ser de tipo int, sino de tipo string, ademas un isbn puede tener el caracter 'X' como digito de control

Comment: @Japv Según lo que investigué la X es un onceavo "dígito", como tal los ISBN deberían ser de 10 o de 13 dígitos numéricos, por lo cual un ISBN con X debería ser convertido antes a ISBN 13 (según lo que leí). Supongo que da dependerá del autor cómo maneje esos casos

Comment: @EduardoJiménez, no es tan así, entra aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/492951/como-determinar-que-un-isbn-es-v%c3%a1lido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma en la que podrías hacer más fácil la búsqueda de tus libros es mediante Streams.

Como recomendación, te diré que hay libros con ISBN 13, por lo que un dato tipo `int` sería insuficiente, por lo que te recomiendo cambiar el ISBN a String o a long.

Imaginemos que tu clase libro es de la siguiente forma:

```java
public class Book {
    private final Long ISBN;
    private final String title;

    public Book(long ISBN, String title) {
        this.ISBN = ISBN;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Long getISBN() {
        return ISBN;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(ISBN).concat(" : ").concat(title);
    }
}
```

Podríamos encontrar el libro mediante su ISBN con [Stream.filter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) y como el ISBN es único lo podemos limitar al primer resultado con [Stream.limit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit(long))

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                new Book(9788440719171L, "El archipiélago en llamas"),
                new Book(9788475743233L, "De la tierra a la luna"),
                new Book(9788484470076L, "Escuela de Robinsones")
        ));
        Long ISBN = 9788440719171L;
        Book search = books.stream()
                .filter(book -> book.getISBN().equals(ISBN))
                .limit(1)
                .findFirst().orElse(null);

        System.out.println(search);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
9788440719171 : El archipiélago en llamas
```

Comment: No creo que el OP está listo para usar Stream, pero me parece buena respuesta.

Comment: disculpa ¿Qué significa OP?

Comment: @francesco14 se refiere a esto [¿Qué significa OP?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1304/193364)

Answer (score 2):

Supongamos que la estructura de tu clase `Libro` sea

```
public class Libro {
    private int isbn;
    private String titulo;

    public Libro(int isbn, String titulo) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public int getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }
}
```

Creamos una clase `ProbarLibro` para crear los libros y realizar la búsqueda de un libro.

```
public class ProbarLibro {
    //Creamos un ArrayList de libros
    static ArrayList<Libro>libros= new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        //creamos 2 libros
        Libro libro1=new Libro(1, "Titulo 1");
        Libro libro2=new Libro(2, "Titulo 2");
        //Agregamos los libros al ArrayList de libros
        libros.add(libro1);
        libros.add(libro2);
        
        //Buscamos un libro con isbn=2
        Libro libroencontrado= encontrarLibro(2);
        
        //Mostramos la búsqueda del libro
        if(libroencontrado!=null){
            System.out.println("Datos del libro encontrado:");
            System.out.println("ISBN: "+libroencontrado.getIsbn());
            System.out.println("Titulo: "+libroencontrado.getTitulo());
        }else
            System.out.println("No se ha encontrado ningún libro");
           
    }
    
//método para la búsqueda de un libro, esto es lo que preguntas

    public static Libro encontrarLibro(int isbnrecibido){
        Libro libroRespuesta = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < libros.size(); i++) {               
            if(isbnrecibido == libros.get(i).getIsbn()) {
                libroRespuesta= libros.get(i);                   
            }                        
        }        
        return libroRespuesta;
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Como recomendación, sería útil poner un break dentro del if, para que una vez que lo encuentre, se detenga el ciclo

Comment: Tienes razón, gracias por la recomendación

Answer (score 2):

Lo que estas realizando es casì correcto, generalmente buscamos un objeto en base a el valor de alguna propiedad en este caso en base a el ISBN.

Pero recuerda que si este valor es de tipo String, la comparaciòn debe realizarse mediante la funciòn `.equals(..)` o `.equalsIgnoreCase(..)` que compara la cadena de texto contra un objeto ignorando mayúsculas y minúsculas. :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < coleccion1.size(); i++) {
     //if(isbnrecibido == coleccion1(i).getisbn()) {
     if(isbnrecibido.equalsIgnoreCase(coleccion1(i).getisbn())) { //*revisa si son iguales!
       librorespuesta = coleccion1.get(i);
       System.out.println(coleccion1.get(i));
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

No te entendí muy bien tu pregunta pero creo que la solución a tu problema es algo así

```
public Libro getBook(Lista<Libro> libro, int id){
    Libro<T> aux = this.front; //Siendo este el 1 libro de la lista
    Libro respuestaLibro = new Libro();
    int i = 0;
    while(i<libro.size()){
        if(aux != null)
            if(id.equals(aux.id)){
                respuestaLibro = aux;   
            }
            i++;
            aux = aux.next;
    }
    
    return respuestaLibro;
}
```

Como ya te dije en el comentario ten cuidado con == sirve para comparar direcciones y tipos primitivos. El código que te dije es un ejemplo de lo que creo que te pasa.