# ¿Cómo determinar que un ISSN es válido?

Tags: c#, issn

### **Esta pregunta es autorespondida.**

En días anteriores había compartido un algoritmo para determinar si un **ISBN** es válido: [¿Como determinar que un ISBN es válido?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/492951/como-determinar-que-un-isbn-es-v%c3%a1lido)

Ahora comparto un algoritmo para determinar si un **ISSN** es válido.

Comment: Si la pregunta es autorespondida, el codigo va obviamente en la respuesta, asi que no entiendo el voto negativo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El **ISSN** (International Standard Serial Number/Número Internacional Normalizado de Publicaciones Seriadas) es un número único que permite identificar publicaciones en serie, tales como diarios, folletos, revistas, etc.

El **ISSN** está constituido por 8 caracteres separados por dos grupos de 4 caracteres cada uno, que para mejor legibilidad pueden separarse usando el guión, aunque no es obligatorio. La última cifra ubicada en la octava posición sirve como dígito de control. Los primeros 7 caracteres del **ISSN** pueden ser dígitos del **0-9**, mientras la octava posición, puede ser igualmente un caracter del **0-9**, o el caracter **'X'**, que representa al número **10**.

A continuación se muestra el algoritmo para determinar si un **ISSN** es válido:

```
static class Validaciones
{
   public static bool ValidarCalculoISSN(string issn)
   {
      bool validado = false;
      var indiceX = issn.IndexOf('X');
                                        
      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(issn))
      {
         if (indiceX == 7 || indiceX == -1)
         {
            var listaNumeros = new List<int>();
            var ponderacion = 8;

            for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
            {
               listaNumeros.Add(Convert.ToInt32(issn[i].ToString()) * ponderacion);
               ponderacion--;
            }

            var modulo = 11 - (listaNumeros.Sum() % 11);
            var digitoControl = (issn[7] == 'X') ?
                                 10 : Convert.ToInt32(issn[7].ToString());

            validado = (digitoControl == modulo);
         }
      }
            
      return validado;
   }
}
```

Esta función recibe como parámetro un **string**, que sería el **ISSN** a validar y devuelve un **bool**, de manera que si retorna **true**, el **ISSN** es válido, caso contrario no es válido.

Se declaran dos variables:

**validado:** Variable de tipo **bool**, usada para determinar si el **ISSN** pasado como parámetro es válido o no, el valor que tendrá esta variable al final de la ejecución del algoritmo será el valor de retorno de la función. Esta variable se inicializa en **false**.

**indiceX:** Variable de tipo entero, que se usa para saber si existe el caracter **'X'** en el **ISSN** pasado como parámetro. Esta variable guarda la posición del primer caracter **'X'** encontrado dentro del **ISSN** en caso de que halla al menos una coincidencia y en caso de que no exista el caracter **'X'** su valor sería **-1**.

Posteriormente se pregunta si el **ISSN** pasado como parámetro está vacío o no, de estar vacío se retorna **false**, indicando que no es un **ISSN** válido, de no estar vacío se pregunta entonces si existe el caracter **'X'** y de existir que solo aparezca en la posición 8 (la última) del **ISSN**.

Visto todo lo anterior se procede a determinar si el dígito de control del **ISSN** es correcto, dicho dígito de control corresponde al octavo caracter del **ISSN**, es decir la última posición.

Para calcular el dígito de control del **ISSN** se asigna una ponderación a cada posición del **ISSN** de **8** a **2** en sentido decreciente, iniciando desde la primera posición del **ISSN**, es decir, el valor de la primera posición del **ISSN** se multiplica por **8**, el segundo por **7**, y así sucesivamente hasta llegar a la séptima posición del **ISSN**
cuyo valor se multiplica por **2**. Todas estas multiplicaciones se suman y se halla el **módulo 11** de dicha suma, este resultado obtenido se resta a **11** y este resultado final seria el dígito de control, si este dígito de control es **10**, se sustituye dicho valor por el caracter **'X'**.

Lo descrito anteriormente es lo que sucede dentro del **ciclo for**, es decir se van realizando las multiplicaciones y agregando dichas multiplicaciones a la **lista de enteros listaNumeros**. Posteriormente se suman todos los elementos de la lista, a esta suma se le halla el **módulo 11**, y este resultado se resta al número **11**, todo este cálculo se almacena en la **variable módulo**. A continuación se guarda en la **variable digitoControl** el valor que tiene la última posición del **ISSN** pasado como parámetro, y si es **'X'**, dicha variable guardará el valor **10**.

Si las **variables modulo** y **digitoControl** son iguales entonces el **ISSN** está correctamente validado y la función retornará **true**, caso contrario retornará **false**.