# No encuentro la solución, ¿Como sacar el dígito de control de un ISBN-10?

Tags: java

Estoy intentando calcular el digito de control de un ISBN que se obtiene multiplicando cada dígito por su posición (siendo el dígito de la izquierda el que ocupa la posición 1), sumando los resultados obtenidos y hallar el resto de dividir por 11, adjunto lo que llevo ya que no me da los resultados esperados:

```
    int control=0;
    
    Scanner N=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Introduce los 9 primeros numeros del ISBN para calcular el caracter de control:");
    String isbn=N.nextLine();
    
    for(int i=0;i<isbn.length();i++) {
        control=control+isbn.charAt(i)*(i+1);
    }
    control=control%11;
    
    if(control>-1 && control<10) {
        System.out.println("ISBN completo: "+isbn+"-"+control);
    }else {
        System.out.println("ISBN completo: "+isbn+"-X");
    }
```

Comment: Le añado el ISBN: 843654201 y me devuelve como caracter de control 4, cuando deberia ser 0

Comment: Entra aki https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/492951/como-determinar-que-un-isbn-es-v%c3%a1lido

Comment: Por lo que han comentado en las respuestas, cabe notar que el tipo primitivo `char` y su correspondiente clase envolvente [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) en realidad no contienen estrictamente ni ASCII ni UTF16, sino caracteres [Unicode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html). Que gracias al trabajo del [*Consorcio*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consorcio_Unicode) dichos valores coincidan por razones distintas es otro tema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estás hablando de multiplicar dígitos. Pero [`charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) devuelve un carácter.

Internamente es un número que representa dicho carácter en la codificación UTF-16. Dichos números están entre el 40 y 60. Mucho más que 0 y 10.

Puedes resolverlo así:

```
for(int i=0; i<isbn.length(); i++) {
  control += Character.getNumericValue(isbn.charAt(i)) * (i + 1); 
}
```

Me dio el resultado esperado (0).

Comment: correctísimo, disculpa, acabo de ver tu respuesta

Comment: @techdobycon no hay nada que disculpar, contestamos casi al mismo tiempo

Comment: Alternativamente puedes restarle '0' al carácter. Siempre y cuando sean todos dígitos. Aprovechando que tienen códigos consecutivos.

Comment: muchas gracias, pensaba que si el programa no me daba error era porque reconocia el caracter como un numero entero y podria hacerme la multiplicación

Answer (score 0):

Espero que te sirva:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            String isbn="843654201";
        
       
            int tot = 0;
            for ( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
            {
                int digit = Integer.parseInt( isbn.substring( i, i + 1 ) );
                tot += ((10 - i) * digit);
            }             
            String checksum = Integer.toString( (11 - (tot % 11)) % 11 );
            if ( "10".equals( checksum ) )
            {
                checksum = "X";
            }             
            System.out.println(checksum);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Como que vendría mejor una explicación eh...

Comment: claro, si cambias el valor del isbn, pues te calcula el checksum. Fuera bromas, ya ha respondido infinit3loop, y con una explicación mejor del problema, de hecho le he dado un positivo, cuando lo he visto ya había publicado mi respuesta, la he dejado porque creo que mejoro el cálculo de checksum, pero en unos días borraré la respuesta.

Comment: No borres la respuesta. No hay ninguna regla en contra de responder preguntas que ya tienen respuesta... siempre y cuando no copies y pegues la respuesta obviamente. Dar múltiples opciones es siempre mejor que dar una única respuesta al fin y al cabo. Lo que si, tal como dice el compañero @Cris223511.dev, añade una explicación de tu código. Porque las respuestas que son solo código pueden no resultar claras, especialmente si haces tantas operaciones "extrañas" que no aparecen en la pregunta. Explica por qué tu código funciona, eso no puede hacerlo infinit3Loop_ ni nadie por ti.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces el CharAt te trae el carácter ascii, por lo tanto, el valor ascii numérico se ***'1'*** es diferente al valor numerico ***1***. Es decir el carácter '0' tiene un valor ascii de 48, y así sucesivamente. Hasta el '9' que es 57. Es con estos valores con los que estas calculando.

Tienes que utilizar su valor mumerico. para ello restale '0' al CharAt()

```
control=control+(isbn.ChartAt(i) - '0')+(i+1)
```

Comment: Efectivamente, si restas dos `char` en realidad estás restando su valor ASCII, con lo cual si a cualquier `char` de número le restas `'0'` (porque es el primero), siempre obtendrás su valor "numérico" :)